# pl.polidea.coverflow refresh specific item

Tags: android, gallery, coverflow

I m using pl.polidea.coverflow ( http://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/ , which extends android.widget.Gallery ) to display some images downloaded form the internet.

As it s a bit long to download and cache all images in the coverflow , I create the coverflow with placeholder images and as I asynchrononously download images, I call the adapter to put the downloaded bitmap in the bitmapMap

```
public void replaceBitmap(TMP_CoverflowItem item)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = item.bmpData;
    bitmapMap.put(item.position, new WeakReference<Bitmap>(bitmap));  


}
```

It works.. but only for images which was never displayed. i supposed other as cached and I m looking for a way to refresh specific items in the coverflow